# Permission Set in Test Class

Tags: failing-tests

I have a test class which fails when the Deferred Sharing is on. Because the test data created by the admin user is not seen by another user . and I get insufficient privileges error when i run as new user and do an update. Is there a way that i can create a permission set in the test class and assign to the user so that sharing rules won't be a problem and the test class will pass ? Please suggest.

Comment: Disable deferred sharing recalculation . It is not meant to be left on. Your missing the point of the test as well. It is supposed to be failing with deferred sharing on (typically)

Comment: You found any solution ?

Comment: This has already been answered. Please refer to the [answer here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47328/test-class-and-permission-sets)