# SFDX Package2 Version Create - Custom Object fields are not visible to the user during package version creation

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, custom-object, custom-field

So this error: "SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field" means one of two things:
1. You forgot a field in your soql query you are now trying to use
2. You do not have permissions to access the field

So what is a developer to do when making a package with custom objects?  I have a permission set built and bundled as part of the package, but I do not know how to assign it to the user or the scratch org the "version/create" process is using.

I can duplicate the error by creating a brand new scratch org and pushing everything to it. Once I push everything in the manifest to the scratch org, I run my tests and get the same error. If I then assign the permission set in the package to the user of the scratch org, everything runs fine. But prior to this assignment, my new user in the new scratch org cant access the field. So how do you over come this in packaging?  This is managed package by the way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I assign a permission set to a user in a test context?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47328/how-can-i-assign-a-permission-set-to-a-user-in-a-test-context)

Answer (score 2):

So the answer to this is in Profiles and not Permission sets. Permission sets are awesome, and you need to include some with varying levels in your packages so admins can easily assign correct permissions to different profiles. But as far as I can tell those permission sets can only be assigned in a script you run after installation.  So you need to update at least the Admin profile with access to object and fields that are necessary in testing.

In your package manifest put the following and then pull it using source/retrieve

    `<types>
        <members>Admin</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>`

Then in the Admin.profile-meta.xml that is pulled, you can add permissions to the objects that need to be accessed.

Comment: This is worth a look as well. 

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47328/how-can-i-assign-a-permission-set-to-a-user-in-a-test-context